# Encoding string with non-ascii characters

Tags: php, hex, encode

I have a string such as this - `Panamá`. I need to convert this string to `Panam\xE1` so it's readable in a JavaScript file I'm generating using PHP.

Is there a function to encode this in PHP? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any other metaformat except ASCII that you are using, like e.g. JSON or XML? With those, you would delegate proper transport (including encoding/decoding and escaping/unescaping) to the according metaformat library, which is preferrable to rolling your own thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your input is in the latin-1 encoding then `ord` and `dechex` will do what you want:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '/[\x80-\xff]/',
    function($match) {
        return '\x'.dechex(ord($match[0]));
    },
    $input);
```

If your input is in any other encoding then you would need to know what encoding that is and adapt the solution accordingly. Note that in this case it would not be possible to use specifically the `\x##` notation in the JS output in all cases.

Comment: Just a little typo here: `$m[0]`-> `$match[0]`

Comment: How about if they aren't in the latin-1 encoding? Is there a way to check for all?

Comment: @Lex: You have to know what you input encoding is (or just arbitrarily declare that you only accept encoding X and/or Y). [It is not possible to guess and be consistently correct](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file).

Comment: @Phil_1984_: Sorry to say that, but you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Jon Yes you are absolutely correct.  I was wrong in my comment.  But I still think my answer looks at the bigger picture rather than just trying to escape the string.  You have not shown how you would send your $result variable from php in to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

My rule is,

> If you try to encode or escape data using *preg_replace* or
>   *using massive mapping arrays* or *str_replace*, **STOP** you are probably doing it wrong.

All it takes is one missed or eroneous mapping (*and you WILL miss some mappings*) then you end up with code that doesn't work in all cases and code which corrupts your data in some cases.  Whole libraries have been written already dedicated to doing the translations for you (e.g. iconv) and for escaping data, you should use the proper PHP function.

If you plan on outputting the data to a browser (the fact you want to encode for javascript suggests this) then I suggest using UTF8 encoding.  If your data is in latin-1, use the [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function.

Whether your PHP string contains ASCII characters or not, to send any data from PHP to JS you should **ALWAYS** [use the json_encode function](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/scalar.php).

PHP code

```
$your_encoding = 'latin1';
$panama = "Panamá";

//Get your data in utf8 if it isnt already
$panama = iconv($your_encoding, "utf-8", $panama);

$panama_encoded = json_encode($panama);
echo "var js_panama = " . $panama_encoded . ";";
```

JS Output

```
var js_panama = "Panam\u00e1";
```

*Even though JSON supports unicode, it may not be compatible with your non UTF-8 javascript file.  This is not a problem because the json_encode PHP function will escape unicode characters by default.*

Comment: You do realize that `json_encode` only works on UTF-8 input, right?

Comment: OK I made an assumption, but if you're a PHP developer (or working with websites in general for that matter), UTF-8 should be your encoding.  If you are reading strings from elsewhere which are not utf8, then simply use utf8_encode.  But thanks I will make this clearer in my answer.

Comment: `utf8_encode` *also* assumes the input encoding, so it gives you absolutely nothing regarding generality. Actually, in the cases where `utf8_encode` can be used then the "manual" solutions with replacing can also be used just as well.

Comment: @Jon You are absolutely correct.  But i was never intending to create a magic solution which will work for any encoding.  As you have pointed out, it is not possible.  But this method also fixes security issues further on down the line such as XSS attacks, and doesnt use the messy preg_replace or str_replace.  Your solution will work but I feel that this way is a better method of getting the data in to javascript.  I have added iconv instead of utf8_encode so the OP can specify the encoding.  Perhaps my point is a bit clearer now.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
$str = "Panamá";
$str = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
    $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', current($m));
    return sprintf("\x%s", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
}, $str);

echo $str;
```

Output (Source Code):

```
Panam\xE1
```

Comment: `\x` notation in JavaScript only works for the latin-1 encoding. It's meaningless to try to encode Unicode code points above U+FF.

Comment: Will this work for all non-ascii characters? Such as á, í, é, ó, ü, ú, ñ etc?

Comment: @Lex Just test it and you see it :D (e.g. `Panamáá, í, é, ó, ü, ú, ñ` => `Panam\xE1\xE1, \xED, \xE9, \xF3, \xFC, \xFA, \xF1`)

Comment: @Lex As you can see it works ^, so is your question answered or what do you need?